# Function not evaluating as expected due to ID10T error

Tags: r, function, syntax

For simplicity: `mydf <- data.frame(college=c(1,2,1,0,3))`

```
> str(mydf)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ college: num  1 2 1 0 3
```

I had a bunch of repeated code elements where I set up to conducte ordinal logistic regression by first factoring and setting the reference level as follows:

```
> mydf$college <- factor(mydf$college)
> relevel(mydf$college, ref="2")
[1] 1 2 1 0 3
Levels: 2 0 1 3
> str(mydf$college)
 Factor w/ 4 levels "0","1","2","3": 2 3 2 1 4
```

I wrote a function to do this so I could call it and have better programming etiquette:

```
factor_level <- function(ds, var, referent){
  ds[[var]] <- factor(ds[[var]])
  ds[[var]] <- relevel(ds[[var]], ref=referent)
}
```

However, when I call the function, I don't get any error, but I don't get a factored result either.

```
> factor_level(ds = mydf, var="college", referent= "2")
> str(mydf$college)
 num [1:5] 1 2 1 0 3
```

I'm sure it is syntax, but I've not been able to figure out why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Things you do inside a function do not change anything outside the function (unless you do special stuff that you shouldn't do). Your function needs to return the modified factor `ds` and when you call the function you assign the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate what joran means in his comment, your function ought to be

```
factor_level <- function(var, referent){
  var <- factor(var)
  relevel(var, ref=referent)
}
```

Then you can call:

```
mydf$college <- factor_level(mydf$college, "2")
```

I don't think you gain anything by making use of separate data and variable name arguments in this context.  Just pass it the vector.

If I understand the question in your comment correctly, applying thus to multiple vectors in a data frame can be done with

```
mydf [c ("var1", "var2", ..., "varn")] <-
    lapply(mydf [c ("var1", "var2", ..., "varn")],
          factor_level, "2")
```

Comment: Thank you. I was a little confused.  Is this a better place for two apply statements where I just subset columns on an index created from a vector of names I want to change the same way with same referent?

Comment: See the addition to my answer. I hope I understood your question correctly

Comment: Ah, was thinking more like skipping my function all together and doing something like: `mydf[c("var1","var2"),] <- apply(mydf[c("var1","var2"),], 2, factor)`  followed by `mydf[c("var1","var2"),] <- apply(mydf[c("var1","var2"),], 2, function(x) relevel(x, ref = "2"))` but I could not get it to work.

Comment: In your case, you'd be better off with `mydf[c("var1","var2"),] <- lapply(mydf[c("var1","var2"),], factor)` followed by `mydf[c("var1","var2"),] <- lapply(mydf[c("var1","var2"),], function(x) relevel(x, ref = "2"))`. I believe `apply` coerces the object to a matrix, so it's best to use `lapply` when working with columns of a data frame.

Comment: Thank you. @Benjamin  In my example, I had rows and columns backwards, but I get the gist.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that R function doesn't change the original input, except the replacement function, which behaves like modifying the original input. So you need to do this:

```
factor_level <- function(ds, var, referent){
  ds[[var]] <- factor(ds[[var]])
  ds[[var]] <- relevel(ds[[var]], ref=referent)
  ds
}

mydf <- factor_level(ds = mydf, var="college", referent= "2")
```

or you need to define a replacement function (like `<-` or `[<-` in R) like this:

```
`factor_level<-` <- function(ds, var, value){
  ds[[var]] <- factor(ds[[var]])
  ds[[var]] <- relevel(ds[[var]], ref=value)
  ds
}

factor_level(mydf, var="college") <- "2"
```

But the replacement function behaves quite oddly in this case, I think you shouldn't use it.